# Getting connection aborted, remote disconnected error in python

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "http://www.ticketcity.com/kansas-city-tickets/arrowhead-stadium-tickets/arizona-cardinals-at-kansas-city-chiefs-nov-11-2018-2653648.html"

headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }

html = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote
>   end closed connection without response',))

Anyone can please help in this issue?

Comment: Your code snippet fails with "TypeError: get() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)". Please post a proper MCVE

Comment: Also once the code is fixed, I get a 200 response, so either you had a momentary issue (network issue, remote server down or restarting etc) that can't be reproduced or there's something blocking the connection on your network (proxy, firewall...).

Comment: Works well for me! with getting 200 response

Comment: Yeah..That was typo error..However i am getting same issue. Might by firewall issue...Is there any way i can check if it is being blocked by firewall

Answer (score 0):

Your argument isn't match. fix it by remove seconds `headers`:

```
In [48]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...: 
    ...: import requests
    ...: 
    ...: url = "http://www.ticketcity.com/kansas-city-tickets/arrowhead-stadium-tickets/arizona-cardinals-at-kansas-city-chiefs-nov-11-2018-2653648.html"
    ...: 
    ...: headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }
    ...: 
    ...: html = requests.get(url, headers)
    ...: 
    ...: 


In [49]: 

In [49]: html.status_code
Out[49]: 200
```

Comment: Yeah..That was typo error..However i am getting same issue.

Comment: @yashul What you got? show us and so we can help you.

Comment: this time i am getting 503...which is error.. can any please provide solution.